# How to change the position of a canvas child on mouse move?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have many UI elements in a canvas object "CanvasContain". On mouse move I want to offset all the UI elements in that canvas. I tried with the name of the canvas, it is working fine:

```
foreach(UIElement child in CanvasContain.Children)
{
    if (child != null)
    { 
        Canvas2.Offset -= position - LastMousePosition;
        Canvas3.Offset -= position - LastMousePosition;
    }
}
```

But when I try with `child.offset` it is not working. How can I change the offset dynamically?

Comment: btw, i am using ZoomableCanvas for zomming and panning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust the Canvas Left and Top properties for each child:

```
foreach(UIElement child in CanvasContain.Children)
{
    double x = Canvas.GetLeft(child);
    double y = Canvas.GetTop(child);
    Canvas.SetLeft(child, x - (position.X - LastMousePosition.X));
    Canvas.SetTop (child, y - (position.Y - LastMousePosition.Y));
}
```

Note I dropped the test for `child != null` which isn't necessary.